# Adding elements after DOM Ready and make them visible without the need of an event handler

Tags: jquery, dom, element

Adding an element after the dom is ready without the need of an event handler:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var $body = $('body');
var strLoading = '<div id="ajax_loader" style="display:none">Loading ...</div>';
$body.append(strLoading); // add loading text to dom
var $Loading = $('#ajax_loader');

$('some unrelated element already available at time of dom ready').click(function{

$Loading.toggle(); // show loading message

LOAD SOME CONTENT THROUGH AJAX

$Loading.toggle(); // hide loading message

});
});
```

I would now like to show and hide it on demand like so:

```
$('some unrelated element already available at time of dom ready').click(function{

$Loading.toggle(); // show loading message

LOAD SOME CONTENT THROUGH AJAX

$Loading.toggle(); // hide loading message

});
```

It seems the element is not available in the dom. how can I add it and make it be seen later on.

UPDATE:
I have no idea why it isn't working at my end I just created this fiddle and it works fine there.

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/w3pN5/)

Comment: I don't know what you have done, but next time, try to past proper code and not code with syntax highlight information.

Comment: @FelixKling:  lol, I've never seen that before. Looks messy

Comment: i don't see any problem with the code :(

Comment: @Caren: Is your code in a `$(document).ready()` enclosure or at the end of the body tag?

Comment: @Caren: Well, now it is ok, but originally it looked like this: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/e89e5ee9-8d85-470d-9cf8-279eca4543da/view-source (see all the weird divs and spans)

Comment: @Felix that is weird :) sorry about that .

Comment: @qwertymk made changes to the code

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Try to find the problem somewhere else.

Which element are you having problems with? Why do you think that the element is not available? Did you try $().length or something similar? If the toggle doesn't seem to have any effect, it might be due to additional JS or CSS that you didn't share with us.

Comment: The first code block prepares adding the element as last child of the body after dom is ready. Once the user clicks on a specified element i want to show the Loading Element which is the last child of body and after the ajax finished, hide the element again. the only code for the css is #ajax_loader { display: none }

Answer (score 0):

you can simply include your script just before your closing body tag.